# React js isn't running my App.js on localhost:3000

Tags: reactjs

When I type npm start in terminal, in localhost:3000 in browser, it opens index.js instead of App.js, I want to open App.js, how do I fix this?

Comment: In most React apps, `index.js` starts `app.js`. But you need to include your code, how else can we see what's wrong with it?

Answer (score 0):

First of all: Welcome to StackOverflow!

Usually your `index.js` renders your `app.js`. Then the content of the `index.js` would look similiar to this:

```
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';

ReactDOM.render(
  <App />
);
```

And your `app.js` content would look similiar to:

```
import React from 'react';

const App = () => {
  return(
    <div>I am the app content.</div>
  )
};

export default App;
```

So your browser would still start the `index.js` but renders the content of your `app.js` which contains the `<App />` Component.